# PlayFramework make a function that returns an Integer in Twirl?

Tags: playframework

so here is what I want the function to look like:

```
@getMaxLevel(buildingId : Integer) = @{
    if levelMap.get(buildingId) == null 1 else levelMap.get(buildingId)
}
```

But the problem is when I call this I get an error about a missing bracket, which there isn't (because if I replace the contents of the message with, say, `3` then everything works

How do I tell Twirl to have this as a method I call in my Twirl code?

Answer (score 0):

You are just missing the parenthesis in the `if` clause. The correct syntax is:

```
@getMaxLevel(buildingId : Integer) = @{
    if (levelMap.get(buildingId) == null) 1
    else levelMap.get(buildingId)
}
```

Or better, using `containsKey` instead of getting the value twice:

```
@getMaxLevel(buildingId : Integer) = @{
  if (!levelMap.containsKey(buildingId)) 1
  else levelMap.get(buildingId)
}
```

If you are using Java 8, maybe you don't even need this function since you can use [Map.getOrDefault](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#getOrDefault-java.lang.Object-V-):

```
@getMaxLevel(buildingId : Integer) = @{
  levelMap.getOrDefault(buildingId, 1)
}
```